# Running a php script as a background process using unix

Tags: php, unix, background-process

I am trying to run the php script (below) named daemon.php as a back ground process using unix.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$count = 0;
while(true){
    $count = $count + 1;
    file_put_contents('daemon1.log', $count, FILE_APPEND);
    sleep(1);  
}
?>
```

If I run it in the foreground using the command below

```
php daemon.php
```

The file deamon1.log starts getting written to. Also if I enter the command:

```
ps | grep php
```

I get the out put

```
10573 ttys000    0:00.20 php daemon.php
```

If I try to run it as a background process using the command

```
php daemon.php &
```

I get the console out put

```
[1] 10584
```

And the command

```
ps | grep php
```

Returns

```
10584 ttys000    0:00.02 php daemon.php
```

But nothing is written to deamon1.log. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Unix are you using? I'm running it here under GNU/Linux Debian without any problems.

Comment: i suspect an issue with the user and file writing permissions. the cli user and apache user will not be the same

Comment: I'm using version 11.4.2

Comment: Changing permissions didn't help

Comment: log in as root, `su apache_user -c php daemon.php` see what happens

Comment: Hi Dagon I'm having trouble executing that, getting su:Sorry

Comment: @Dagon seriously? you have so many assumptions about that guys' architecture, and why would running that code as another user make a difference? He's running the program in the same directory he's got the code in.

Comment: if it's being written to in fore-ground then it should run fine in background ... have you tried waiting for it a bit longer?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach.

```
$file_handler = fopen( 'daemon1tempname.log', 'a+') or die ('Can not work with the File!');

$count = 0;
while(true){
    $count = $count + 1;
    fwrite($file_handler, "Test {$count}\n" );
    sleep(1);  
}
fclose($file_handler);
```

Notice the different name of the file. Just make sure you work with a new file.
If that works, test it with the file you want.
If that does not work, then you know it's a permission issue.

Comment: if you don't close the file you won't see any thing written outside.